# How to solve "Remote call returned an error. Member: StartScan(); Exception: (DllNotFoundException) Dll was not found." issue..?

Tags: tosca

Remote call returned an error. Member: StartScan(); Exception: (DllNotFoundException) Dll was not found.
[Error in XScan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZpxQ.png)

while doing scan in Tosca tool getting this issue.. any one help me on this..?

I tried to give dll home path in environment variables, but no luck...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue yesterday. I updated the windows with latest available updates and restarted the system. this solved the issue for me. If your are still facing this issue you can try this solution.